# How I receive and process WhatsApp messages on my ASP.NET Core MVC app with Twilio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Im trying to build a botchat in WhatsApp, using ASP.NET Core MVC, C# and Twilio.
I can send messages to a WhatsApp (my) number. But I don't know **how to receive and do something with those income messages.**

The Twilio docs tutorial is not comprehensive. Someone did it successful with C#?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Evangelist here...

Sorry that you're having such trouble finding the sample code that you are looking for.

For context, the code for processing inbound Whatsapp messages is the exact same as for SMS messages as noted in the Twilio docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/quickstart/csharp#receive-and-reply-to-messages-from-whatsapp).

You should be able to use the C# controller in the Programmable SMS Quickstart (in our docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-core#receive-and-reply-to-inbound-sms-messages-with-aspnet-core)). Take a look and feel free to reach out if this does not serve your purposes. I can be reached via email at corey@twilio.com.